# Sharepoint 2010 on domain with local accounts not populating people picker

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have an instance of Sharepoint setup for dev right now. The server OS is on my AD domain, but the sharepoint app is setup using local accounts (because I'm not a domain admin).  I am logged onto the box using my domain creds, however.

People picker does not seem to be working at all at this point. Querying for users returns neither the local users of the machine nor the AD users.

What should I try to do?  Ideally, it's using local accounts as service accounts, but able to pull AD users for membership purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably should have been obvious to me, but the solution was to  have the service account be an AD member.  It didn't have to be an admin, just a member.